# Jquery UI Dialog Box

Tags: php, jquery

When I click on delete link it directly deletes it.
I am making Jquery UI dialog box to prompt Y/N.
It should prompt Yes/No. If yes- deleted or No -Original State.

Here is My PHP Code for that:

```
echo "<td><a name='delete' href='product_listing_delete.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "' onclick='call()' >Delete</a></td><tr>";
```

Here is my javascript code for that:

```
<script>

        function call() {
            $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
                    .html('<div><h6>Yes or No?</h6></div>')
                     .dialog({
                         modal: true, title: 'message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                         width: 'auto', resizable: false,
                         buttons: {
                             Yes: function () {
                                 doFunctionForYes();
                                 $(this).dialog("close");
                             },
                             No: function () {
                                 doFunctionForNo();
                                 $(this).dialog("close");
                             }
                         },
                         close: function (event, ui) {
                             $(this).remove();
                         }
                     });
        }

        function doFunctionForYes() {
            alert("Yes");
            $('#msg').show();
        }

        function doFunctionForNo() {
            alert("No");
            $('#msg').show();
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: What is the exact issue?

Comment: I have made a alertbox it should prompt yes or no, for further proceed. Instead it directly deletes it, without prompting Y/N.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make some changes:

```
echo "<td><a name='delete' href='product_listing_delete.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "' onclick='call()' >Delete</a></td><tr>";
```

this will directly delete your record by without prompting any kind of alert because you are providing a direct URL to delete.

Make these changes:

```
echo "<td><a name='delete' class='delete' id='".$row['id']."'>Delete</a></td><tr>";
```

JS:

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
    if(confirm('Are you sure'))
    {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        // ajax call to delete the record on the behalf of id
    }
});
```